# Regex combining capturing group with quantifier for SEPA bank numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

**Goal:**
I am trying to create a more efficient regular expression to flexibly capture SEPA bank numbers for form validation.

**Background:** 
SEPA IBAN numbers have this pattern: NL88ABNA1234567890

**My question** is concerning the last 9 or 10 numbers at the end e.g. 0123456789.
I want to allow any combination of space characters and dashes as the numbers are sanitised before submission, e.g.:-

- 0123456789
- 01-23-45-67-89
- 01 23 45 67 89
- 01 - 23 - 45 - 67 - 89
- 012 345 67 89
- etc etc

I can achieve this with the following:-
`(\d(?:\s[\s-]\s|[\s-])?\d(?:\s[\s-]\s|[\s-])?\d(?:\s[\s-]\s|[\s-])?\d(?:\s[\s-]\s|[\s-])?\d(?:\s[\s-]\s|[\s-])?\d(?:\s[\s-]\s|[\s-])?\d(?:\s[\s-]\s|[\s-])?\d(?:\s[\s-]\s|[\s-])?\d(?:\s[\s-]\s|[\s-])?\d?)`

But it's not very elegant

I tried combining capturing group with a quantifier but it only returns the last digit:-

`(\d(?:\s?[\s-]\s?)?){9,10}`

*How can I achieve this more efficiently & check the whole number not just last digit?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex with optional spaces and hyphen following your digits:

```
/((?:\d[\s-]*){9,10})/
```

`[\s-]*` will allow 0 or more spaces and hyphens after each digit.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bQ3zF9/2)